# Android: get height of tab bar?

Tags: android, tabs, height

Is there any way I can get the height of the tab bar in Android? Its getHeight() method seems to only return 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code .

```
   for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout =(RelativeLayout)tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
            relativeLayout.getChildCount();

            TextView tabhostText = (TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);

            tabhostText.setTextSize(20.0f); // you can set the TextSize of your tab also
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 30;

        }
```

It will work .

Comment: I tried it in onCreate method, but heights are all -1, maybe I should try getting it after created?  EDIT: I tried it afterward, it did not work either.

Comment: Thanks but did you actually read my question? My question is how to GET the height but not SET the height. Thanks!

Comment: And what if tab widget is not in a relative layout? Or is it the default layout Android uses for tab widget?