# How to get Tabs Height of Fragment Tab Host in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

Hello I am trying to get the height of Tab of Fragment Tab Host dynamically in android, but it didn't work for me .

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.container);

mTabHost.addTab(
        mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1",
                getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
        FragmentTab.class, null);


LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)findViewById(R.id.container).getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, mTabHost.getHeight(), 0, 0);
```

Any idea to get height of tabs of FragmentTabHost ?

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to get the height because the view isn't laid out as immediately as you might expect. To get the height as soon as the view is laid out, you add a `ViewTreeObserver` `OnGlobalLayoutListener`.

Here's my solution for getting the height of the content in the tab. This code is in the `onCreateView` method of my Fragment.

```
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        View rootElement = tabView.findViewById(R.id.root_element_of_tab);
        Log.d("The height of this tab is " + rootElement.getHeight());
        // Now that the listener has served its purpose, we can remove it
        tabView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
};
tabView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
```

If you're asking about the height of the small tab label, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053291/android-get-height-of-tab-bar) might help.